# Access MySQL RowDataPacket after using AVG()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to access the object created by this query:

```
   con.query('SELECT AVG(gold) from results', (err,result) => {
       console.log(result[0].AVG(gold))
   })
```

which looks like this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { 'AVG(gold)': 302153.6429 } ]
```

But I get the error

```
ReferenceError: gold is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Using `AS` you can access the value in the object just fine.

```
   con.query('SELECT AVG(gold) AS AverageGold from results', (err,result) => {
       console.log(result[0].AverageGold)
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, AVG() will be considered a function because of the similarity in the syntax. Instead of trying to access the property with the dot operator use the brackets like `result[0]['AVG(gold)']`.